# Use parameters $filter and $expand with VDM generated classes

Tags: java, s4sdk

I used the VDM generator to create client classes for a custom OData service in S/4.
I'm trying to use the generated *Service class to get information from an Entity Set, using custom `$filter` and `$expand` parameters, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do so.
(The `FluentHelperRead` class doesn't have any method for defining custom parameters, like the `ODataQueryBuilder` has).

Right now this is what I'm using (it works):

```
/**
 * Query the I_MaintenancePlan entity set filtered by a list of Maint.Plan IDs
 * (The navigation property to_CallHistory will be preloaded via $expand)
 */
public List<MaintenancePlan> getMaintenancePlansById(final Iterable<String> maintPlanIds)
    throws ODataException {

  // Build lightweight $filter with the IDs
  String[] filterParts = StreamSupport.stream(maintPlanIds.spliterator(), false)
    .map(e -> String.format("MaintenancePlan eq '%s'", StringUtils.urlEncode(e)))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
  if (filterParts.length == 0)
    return new ArrayList<>(0);

  String filter = String.join(" or ", filterParts);

  ErpConfigContext erpConfig = new ErpConfigContext(DESTINATION_NAME);

  List<MaintenancePlan> result = ODataQueryBuilder.withEntity(ZCUSTOMODATASRVService.DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH, "I_MaintenancePlan")
      .withoutMetadata()
      .expand("to_CallHistory")
      .param("$filter", filter)
      .withHeader("sap-client", erpConfig.getSapClient().getValue())
      .withHeader("sap-language", erpConfig.getLocale().getLanguage())
      .build()
      .execute(erpConfig)
      .asList(MaintenancePlan.class);

  return result;      
}
```

(`ZCUSTOMODATASRVService` and `MaintenancePlan` are generated VDM classes)

This is what I would like to use (using only the VDM classes):

```
ZCUSTOMODATASRVService service = new DefaultZCUSTOMODATASRVService();

List<MaintenancePlan> result = service.getAllMaintenancePlan()
        .param("$filter", filter)
        .param("$expand", "to_CallHistory")
        .execute(erpConfig);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Could you share the Metadata of your OData service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your metadata, your VDM call could look like this:

```
List<MaintenancePlan> = 
    new DefaultZCUSTOMODATASRVService()
        .getAllMaintenancePlan()
        .filter(MaintenancePlan.CALL_HORIZON.eq("xyz"))
        .select(MaintenancePlan.TO_CALL_HISTORY)
        .execute(erpConfig);
```

You could expand further or reduce the projection via nested selects:

```
List<MaintenancePlan> result = 
      new DefaultZCUSTOMODATASRVService()
          .getAllMaintenancePlan()
          .filter(MaintenancePlan.CALL_HORIZON.eq("xyz"))
          .select(MaintenancePlan.TO_CALL_HISTORY
                  .select(MaintenancePlanCallHistory.INDICATOR,
                          MaintenancePlanCallHistory.MAINTENANCE_PLAN
                   )
           )
           .execute(erpConfig);
```

Comment: Here's my service metadata: https://pastebin.com/8YxpjWwy
In my scenario this solution would work if I could do several individual reads (one for each Id I need) in a $batch request, but I also don't know it that's possible with VDM.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed my answer based on your concrete metadata. This is how you can retrieve multiple MaintenancePlans at a time. What do you mean by `one for each id` in a batch request? Do you mean instead of writing a query, you would like to retrieve simply multiple MaintenancePlans by ID in one batch?

Comment: Thanks for that, it's good to know how I can do multi-level selects with VDM.
Answering your question: Yes, I have several MaintenancePlan IDs I need to read.
If I have let's say 100 IDs, it's not practical to create a filter tree that deep and send it in a query (I might even have problems with URLs being cropped).
Ideally it would be a $batch request with 100 individual reads inside.

Comment: Please watch the release notes for updates on this matter. If the other answer was helpful, kindly ask you to accept the answer.